# Centering Cloud Icon to Middle Right of Nav Border Background

Tags: css, flexbox, responsive-design

I'm building a vertical navigation bar and want to add a cloud icon centered at the right border, directly on the background line.

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="cloud-icon">
    <svg>...</svg>
  </div>
</nav>
```

This is the [code-pen](https://codepen.io/iliketocodealot/pen/ExJWoLd) example. I tried really hard to get this work so any and all feedback would be appreciated.

I've tried to do this with flex-box, css-grid and margins and honestly am quite stuck just getting it to be positioned and stick to the right, let alone be mobile-responsive.

Comment: The issue seems caused by the svg position

Comment: dude! can you elaborate on what you exactly want? Do you wish to move the cloud icon in the center in between while bg and grey bg?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet** using the `<>` icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1):

I edited the `svg` view box to make it centered

```css
:root {
  --beige: #d9d9d9;
}

.contents {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 115%;
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  background-color: var(--beige);
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

nav li {
  padding: 3%;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1rem;
  letter-spacing: 11px;
}

.cloud {
  grid-column: 2;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <div class="contents">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <span class="cloud">
        
<svg width="132" height="60" viewBox="127.037 138.437 123.778 64.061" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M 238.358 176.764 C 236.657 179.93 233.537 182.461 229.622 183.849 C 225.707 185.238 221.287 185.382 217.246 184.252 L 216.805 184.121 C 214.807 183.557 213.071 182.515 211.827 181.134 C 210.583 179.752 209.892 178.097 209.845 176.389 C 209.851 175.101 210.242 173.832 210.985 172.692 C 211.729 171.551 212.802 170.572 214.114 169.837 C 214.538 169.602 214.846 169.253 214.981 168.852 C 215.117 168.451 215.073 168.024 214.856 167.647 C 214.67 167.34 214.384 167.081 214.028 166.896 C 213.672 166.711 213.261 166.608 212.838 166.599 C 212.425 166.599 212.022 166.697 211.678 166.88 C 209.859 167.899 208.354 169.24 207.276 170.801 C 206.199 172.361 205.577 174.1 205.46 175.884 C 205.379 178.154 206.104 180.395 207.552 182.342 C 208.999 184.29 211.107 185.862 213.627 186.873 C 212.264 189.048 210.205 190.889 207.664 192.205 C 205.122 193.522 202.191 194.266 199.173 194.361 C 197.476 194.407 195.791 194.104 194.278 193.482 C 192.765 192.86 191.472 191.939 190.519 190.804 C 190.308 190.565 190.03 190.369 189.708 190.232 C 189.385 190.096 189.028 190.022 188.663 190.018 C 188.303 190.032 187.952 190.114 187.638 190.257 C 187.324 190.4 187.055 190.6 186.854 190.842 C 185.012 193.329 182.069 195.16 178.618 195.965 C 175.168 196.769 171.468 196.487 168.266 195.174 C 165.064 193.862 162.598 191.618 161.367 188.896 C 160.136 186.174 160.232 183.176 161.635 180.508 C 162.29 178.927 163.634 177.592 165.418 176.752 C 167.202 175.911 169.304 175.623 171.333 175.94 C 173.416 176.327 175.236 177.346 176.414 178.786 C 176.699 179.071 177.082 179.283 177.515 179.394 C 177.948 179.505 178.413 179.512 178.85 179.412 C 179.287 179.312 179.679 179.111 179.976 178.833 C 180.273 178.556 180.462 178.214 180.52 177.85 C 180.521 177.552 180.416 177.26 180.219 177.008 C 179.043 175.502 177.398 174.272 175.45 173.439 C 173.502 172.607 171.316 172.2 169.113 172.261 C 166.909 172.322 164.764 172.847 162.89 173.785 C 161.016 174.723 159.48 176.04 158.433 177.607 C 156.666 180.278 155.954 183.322 156.392 186.33 C 152.473 186.747 148.489 186.189 144.974 184.731 C 141.458 183.272 138.578 180.983 136.718 178.168 C 135.866 176.895 135.397 175.477 135.349 174.031 C 137.943 174.637 140.698 174.622 143.281 173.987 C 145.864 173.352 148.162 172.125 149.896 170.455 C 151.056 169.18 152.686 168.235 154.554 167.754 C 156.421 167.273 158.429 167.282 160.289 167.778 C 160.619 167.859 160.967 167.875 161.306 167.826 C 161.644 167.778 161.964 167.665 162.238 167.497 C 162.514 167.33 162.735 167.112 162.885 166.861 C 163.034 166.61 163.107 166.334 163.097 166.056 C 163.014 163.528 163.809 161.031 165.392 158.848 C 166.974 156.665 169.281 154.882 172.052 153.701 C 173.237 153.196 174.536 152.889 175.872 152.799 C 177.207 152.709 178.552 152.837 179.824 153.177 C 179.824 153.42 179.639 153.626 179.569 153.85 C 178.811 156.349 179.088 158.979 180.358 161.338 C 181.29 163.093 182.746 164.633 184.596 165.822 C 186.446 167.011 188.633 167.812 190.96 168.153 C 191.816 168.287 192.686 168.356 193.559 168.358 C 196.505 168.334 199.373 167.584 201.777 166.209 C 204.182 164.834 206.009 162.9 207.015 160.665 C 207.117 160.424 207.152 160.168 207.12 159.915 C 207.087 159.661 206.987 159.417 206.826 159.198 C 206.665 158.979 206.447 158.791 206.187 158.647 C 205.927 158.502 205.632 158.405 205.321 158.362 C 204.812 158.306 204.295 158.388 203.85 158.594 C 203.405 158.801 203.057 159.121 202.862 159.504 C 202.158 161.026 200.885 162.334 199.219 163.248 C 198.084 163.885 196.797 164.324 195.44 164.54 C 194.084 164.755 192.686 164.74 191.337 164.498 C 189.987 164.255 188.715 163.789 187.6 163.129 C 186.485 162.469 185.551 161.63 184.859 160.665 C 183.57 158.411 183.339 155.857 184.209 153.476 L 184.557 152.746 C 185.903 149.933 188.362 147.556 191.552 145.985 C 194.742 144.414 198.485 143.736 202.201 144.056 C 205.918 144.376 209.399 145.676 212.107 147.755 C 214.814 149.833 216.596 152.575 217.176 155.554 C 217.289 155.98 217.583 156.36 218.006 156.63 C 218.43 156.9 218.957 157.043 219.496 157.033 C 223.003 156.986 226.483 157.541 229.704 158.662 C 233.809 160.152 237.021 162.889 238.641 166.278 C 240.261 169.667 240.159 173.435 238.358 176.764 Z" fill="black" transform="matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -3.552713678800501e-15, -3.552713678800501e-15)"/>
</svg>
      </span>
</body>

</html>
```

You can use this https://boxy-svg.com/app tool to edit svg easily by

1. pasting the SVG
2. adjust the `Default view`
3. Export to SVG

[image]